# UIRefreshControl: unrecognized selector sent to instance - absoluteURL

Tags: ios, swift, selector, nsurl, uirefreshcontrol

Before i start, i have went through each and every question relating to this issue. didnt help.

I want to refresh the json contents of my tableView which are fetched from a website.

The URL for each category comes from a different file that has All the categories listed in it.

The code that fetches the content is this

```
func animalSelected(animal: Animal) {

var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: animal.url!)

   self.refresh(animal.url!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(animal.url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        //   println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["posts"] as NSArray
        self.didReceiveResults(jsonResult)

    })
    task.resume()

    delegate?.collapseSidePanels?()

}

func didReceiveResults(results: NSDictionary) {
    var resultsArr: NSArray = results["posts"] as NSArray
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableData = resultsArr
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

My ViewDidLoad method  and the `refresh` method is as shown below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            refresher = UIRefreshControl()
            refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
            refresher!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

            self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

func refresh(categoryUrl : NSURL) {

    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: categoryUrl)

   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(categoryUrl, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err != nil) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["posts"] as NSArray
        self.didReceiveResults(jsonResult)

    })
    task.resume()
    self.refresher.endRefreshing()

           }
```

I need to refresh the contents of the same URL that has been selected i.e refresh the same category.

I get this error : `[UIRefreshControl absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa0b3d73750`

I think it is something related to `absoluteURL`. Bt don't know what is it..

plsss plssssss plssss help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the `absoluteURL` of a `UIRefreshControl` that you think is actually an `NSURL`.

To be exact, your sender in `refresh(categoryUrl: NSURL)` is the `UIRefreshControl` not `NSURL`.

Comment: ok.. bt then how shd i pass the url from the animalSelected function to refresh()

Comment: can you pls help me figure out what needs to done to accomplish what i am trying to do